# JobScheduler stops working after couple of minutes - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I want to get gps location every few minutes. I've used jobScheduler using native interface to run it in the background which works for a few minutes. As soon as it gives getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10 error, the app stops working. It doesn't gives any messages in the debug after that. Plz have a look at the error log below. Thankyou

Main form:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    na = (Native) NativeLookup.create(Native.class);
    if (na != null && na.isSupported()) {
        Log.p("native interface");
        na.getFusedLocationPermission();
        na.jobSchedulerMethod();
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.show();
}
```

Native.java

```
public interface Native extends NativeInterface{
    public void getFusedLocationPermission();
    public void jobSchedulerMethod();
}
```

NativeImpl.class

```
public class NativeImpl {

    JobScheduler jobScheduler;
    private static final int MYJOBID = 1;

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    public void getFusedLocationPermission() {
        if (!com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, "Please allow location permission")) {
            // you didn't get the permission, you might want to return here
//            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((android.app.Activity) MyApplication.getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
//            Log.e("permission", "you didn't get the permission, you might want to return here");
        }
    }

    public void jobSchedulerMethod() {
        Context context = AndroidNativeUtil.getContext();
        Activity activity = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) activity.getSystemService("jobscheduler");

        ComponentName jobService
                = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());
        JobInfo jobInfo
                = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(120000).build();

        int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        if (jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo) > 0) {
            Log.e("job", "Successfully scheduled job: ");
        } else {
            Log.e("job", "RESULT_FAILURE: ");
        }

    }

}
```

Error log 1: "getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10", after this line the app stops working.

```
11-02 11:52:20.931 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia E/job: Successfully scheduled job: 
11-02 11:52:20.941 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: showKeyboard false
11-02 11:52:20.961 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia D/Codename One: sizechanged: 1080 1848 com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneView@cc84777
11-02 11:52:20.971 1824-1854/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.capitaleyenepal.nokia
11-02 11:54:21.081 1824-1824/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{416dfe4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@18f4fee {com.capitaleyenepal.nokia/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia.nokiaStub}} show : true
11-02 11:55:30.501 1824-1824/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia D/NokiaApp: [main] 0:3:9,600 - gps
11-02 11:55:30.511 1824-1824/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: gps checkGPS running
11-02 11:55:31.681 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734582
11-02 11:55:36.681 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734578
11-02 11:55:46.741 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734585
11-02 11:55:51.761 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734582
11-02 11:56:01.781 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734595
11-02 11:56:06.781 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734543
11-02 11:56:11.791 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734539
11-02 11:56:16.811 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734587
11-02 11:56:26.811 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734592
11-02 11:56:31.861 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734566
11-02 11:56:36.811 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734566
11-02 11:56:41.851 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734582
11-02 11:56:46.891 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734544
11-02 11:56:51.871 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734552
11-02 11:56:56.871 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734583
11-02 11:57:01.881 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734574
11-02 11:57:06.921 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734572
11-02 11:57:11.921 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734582
11-02 11:57:16.931 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734562
11-02 11:57:21.941 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734558
11-02 11:57:26.911 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734578
11-02 11:57:31.061 1824-1824/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia D/NokiaApp: [main] 0:5:10,153 - gps
11-02 11:57:31.061 1824-1824/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: gps checkGPS running
11-02 11:57:31.951 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734585
11-02 11:57:37.251 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734579
11-02 11:57:42.281 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734587
11-02 11:57:47.281 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734587
11-02 11:57:52.281 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6734594
11-02 11:57:57.331 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6740921
11-02 11:57:58.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6741087
11-02 11:57:59.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6740856
11-02 11:58:00.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6740856
11-02 11:58:08.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6739376
11-02 11:58:09.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6739368
11-02 11:58:10.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6739125
11-02 11:58:11.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738705
11-02 11:58:12.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738842
11-02 11:58:13.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738967
11-02 11:58:14.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738931
11-02 11:58:15.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738768
11-02 11:58:16.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738634
11-02 11:58:17.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738513
11-02 11:58:18.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738286
11-02 11:58:19.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737996
11-02 11:58:20.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737891
11-02 11:58:21.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737915
11-02 11:58:22.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.67378
11-02 11:58:23.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737786
11-02 11:58:25.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673768
11-02 11:58:26.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737631
11-02 11:58:27.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737799
11-02 11:58:28.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673775
11-02 11:58:29.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737811
11-02 11:58:30.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737817
11-02 11:58:32.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737301
11-02 11:58:33.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737309
11-02 11:58:34.611 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737088
11-02 11:58:35.601 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737008
11-02 11:58:36.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736802
11-02 11:58:37.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736677
11-02 11:58:38.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736791
11-02 11:58:39.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736922
11-02 11:58:40.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673699
11-02 11:58:41.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737056
11-02 11:58:42.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737083
11-02 11:58:43.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737064
11-02 11:58:44.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737282
11-02 11:58:45.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737348
11-02 11:58:46.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737396
11-02 11:58:47.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737422
11-02 11:58:48.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737375
11-02 11:58:49.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737326
11-02 11:58:50.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737596
11-02 11:58:51.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737669
11-02 11:58:52.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673765
11-02 11:58:53.581 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737602
11-02 11:58:54.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673767
11-02 11:58:55.541 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673767
11-02 11:58:56.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737592
11-02 11:58:57.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737599
11-02 11:58:58.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673758
11-02 11:58:59.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737605
11-02 11:59:00.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737605
11-02 11:59:01.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737685
11-02 11:59:02.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737885
11-02 11:59:03.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737965
11-02 11:59:04.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6737916
11-02 11:59:06.581 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6738007
11-02 11:59:10.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.673696
11-02 11:59:11.591 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736834
11-02 11:59:14.581 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736759
11-02 11:59:17.581 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736457
11-02 11:59:19.581 1824-1853/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/System.out: locationUpdated longitudeeee 27.6736243
11-02 11:59:22.011 2044-2044/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.capitaleyenepal.nokiaoverlayDirs =Null
11-02 11:59:22.021 2044-2044/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia-1/lib/arm
11-02 11:59:22.021 2044-2044/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
11-02 11:59:22.071 2044-2060/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
11-02 11:59:22.081 2044-2060/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-02 11:59:22.081 2044-2060/com.capitaleyenepal.nokia E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

[image]

build hint:

```
android.xpermissions - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are overusing GPS background resources and it gets killed by the system. You probably need to use geofencing in the background. This looks more like an Android native issue than a Codename One issue

Comment: but it works in native android.. I want to run the gps after the removal of app from the recent list too, which geofencing doesn't do. The main idea is: once the app is installed, it should be running whether the user runs the app or not.

Comment: We're looking at improving geofencing for 4.0. If this works in a native Android project and doesn't work in our Android app just use include source and see how the native projects differ from one another. Then try to hack the native project we generate to work so you can see what specific setting needs changing.

Comment: ok great... will improved geofencing work even when app is removed from recent app list? And I just have professional subscription account (cannot afford ENTERPRISE one now). I think include source cannot be done in PROFESSIONAL account. Thankyou for the effort.

Comment: Hopefully. I can't guarantee how it will behave but Google changed background behavior in recent versions of Android so we'll try to align to that. Geofencing is a really problematic "hard to debug" feature